# Help! Storing Session Cookies On Server, but there is no garbage collection

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am using PHP 5.2, and I am on a shared host, so I have decieded that i want to store the session cookies, in a folder of my own, but there doesn't seem to be any garbage collection. The cookies are stored there and never deleted. How can i fix this? the code I am using is

```
session_save_path('../example.com/sessions/');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```

Comment: Do you call the mentioned functions before `session_start`? And what value has *session.gc\_divisor*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other part of this is the [session.gc_divisor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) config option. The default value of 100 will give you a 1% chance (gc_probability / gc_divisor) of garbage collection happening on any session start.

To force garbage collection to ALWAYS happen, try using:

```
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 100);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
```

Once you've verified that they garbage collector is indeed working as intended, you should select reasonable values for these settings. 1 - 10% is fine.

Comment: Thats still 1 in 100.  100/1 is 1%.  he needs to set the probability to 10, then you've got a 1 in 10 chance.  Which should be more than sufficient even for a low traffic site.

Comment: @profitphp, 1 / 1 = 1, 100 / 100 = 1. In either case there is a 100% probability that GC will happen. As stated, he should select a reasonable value, forcing 100% probability is just so that he can see that it is actually working as intended.

Comment: ah, i see it says alternately, missed that. I though you were telling him to set them both as you had shown. Which would be 100/1.

Comment: @profitphp: 100/1 = 100 ≙ 10000%. Anything greater than 100% works like 100% as the actual condition for running the garbage collector is like [`session.gc_divisor · rand() < session.gc_probability`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/session/session.c?revision=306938&view=markup#l1426) that is equivalent to `rand() < session.gc_probability / session.gc_divisor`.

Answer (score 1):

What is your session.gc_divisor set to?  If its 10000 the probability of the garbage collector starting will be pretty low.  If its default, 100.  Then there is a 1 in 100 chance the collector will start.  Hit the page a ton of times, see if it clears.

Or set the probability to 100 or the divisor to 1.  Either way, then it will run EVERY time.  Which is overkill, but it should help you find out if its working.  Then set it appropriately.